# Having an issue converting a float to an integer (PHP)

Tags: php, floating-point, integer

Short story, here's my code:

```
var_dump($recentGame->createDate);
var_dump((int) $recentGame->createDate);
```

Is producing the following output:

```
float 1416772859827
int -566347853
```

Why is the output of the typecasted output not this:

```
int 1416772859827
```

Comment: Look at the limits for integers with 32-bit PHP

Comment: **The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is 9223372036854775807.** http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: So what does that createDate represent as an integer? It isn't a standard unix timestamp is it?

Comment: It's an epoch time value, I need to create a dateTime object from it.

Comment: you have milisecounds so: `$seconds = $recentGame->createDate / 1000;
echo date("d-m-Y", $seconds);`

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except for Windows, which is always 32 bit. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.